# MySQL not equals to - isn't working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use not equal select in PhpMtAdmin 5.6.12, MySQL client version: 5.6.12, but it seems not working:

I have tried this queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field <> 05.05.2013

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field <> '05.05.2013'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field <> "05.05.2013"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field != 05.05.2013

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field != '05.05.2013'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field != "05.05.2013"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field not in ('05.05.2013')

...
```

I'm getting error message:

```
ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 38

STR: '

SQL: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field <> \'05.05.2013\'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on PhpMyAdmin 5.6.12. "not equals to" works perfect on other environment.

Answer (score 3):

If field is a date column, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field != '2013-05-05'
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field != STR_TO_DATE("05.05.2013", "%d.%m.%Y")
```

(assuming your date is in the format of day.month.year).